# Webdriver - How can I Assert an attribute exists

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to assert that a particular "ID" contains an attribute of "hidden".  The "hidden" attribute will never actually have a value.  It will exist if I have clicked on a particular button and it will not exist if I haven't clicked on a particular button.  Here is the code:

```
<div id="Callback-time" hidden="">
```

I have tried to get a handle on the attribute as follows but I'm not getting anything:

```
IwebElement CallBackTime = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Callback-time");
String Value = CallBackTime.GetAttribute("hidden");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Value);
```

Comment: `Assert.IsNotNull(Value)`?

Comment: You mean the hidden attribute would exist if you have clicked on button else it will not exist, OR the value inside hidden attribute  will exist if you have clicked the button?

Comment: Sergey thank-you.  That worked ok for me

Comment: Varun, the attribute will appear or disappear depending on whether I click on a button.  It will always have an empty value

Comment: as the solution provided by Sergey worked no issues :)
just one more thing i need to know, did it throw any exception on finding a non existing attribute?

Comment: Varun, interesting you say this because I have found that it does not throw an exception when searching for an attribute that doesn't exist or one that has no value.  When you try to find an element that doesn't exist you get an exception so I have always assumed that if you also search for an attribute that doesn't exist, it should also throw an exception.  In my example, I am able to take out "hidden" and search for an attribute of (for example) "blah".  If I don't assert the attribute then the test will pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two conditions to check are:

1. Button was not clicked and attribute does not exist `<div id="Callback-time">`
2. Button was clicked and attribute does exist `<div id="Callback-time" hidden="">`

You can extract the html for the element as a string and do a basic substring check to tell the difference

```
IwebElement CallBackTime = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Callback-time");
String Value = CallBackTime.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
Assert.AreEqual(Value.Contains("hidden=\"\""), true);
```